# Text box after 2 dropdown selections

Tags: javascript

I'm a VERY basic user of code, and am trying to complete a personal project........

I've managed the 1st part of my project, but for the life of me can't figure out the final part.

In short: I have two drop down options. The second appears depending on the 1st selection, and is populated depending on the 1st choice. 
(This I've done with JavaScript with thanks to previous posts here).

What I need next is depending on the choice in the 2nd drop down a text box appear with a text value. Each choice from the 2nd drop down will produce a different text value / message.

Hope this makes sense and someone can help me out

Comment: Do you want textboxes for all the options which are listed in 2nd dropdown  or only for the value which is selected from 2nd dropdown?

Comment: I'd like a text box to appear for every option chosen from 2nd drop down, but only when selected. Each choice will have a different 'result' in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I have a JSON text and two dropdown lists.

First dropdown list, I will be populating Entities (Applicant, Person, Plan). Second dropdown list will populate attribute values based on entity type which we select from the first dropdown.

After that, I am displaying a textbox based on the value which you select from the second dropdownlist.

Please check below functionality and let me know if need more information.

```js
    var angular = angular.module('myApp', []);

    angular.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.data = [
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"CSRPercent"},
                    {"name":"date"},
                    {"name":"hoursPerWeek"},
                    {"name":"householdSize"}
                ],
                "Entity":"Applicant"
            },
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"age"},
                    {"name":"isPregnant"}
                ],
                "Entity":"Person"
            },
            {
                "Attributes":[
                    {"name":"company"},
                    {"name":"costPerPerson"},
                    {"name":"name"},
                    {"name":"premiumAssistance"},
                ],
                "Entity":"Plan"
            }
        ];
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="dd1" ng-options="item.Entity for item in data">
  </select>

  <select ng-model="dd2" ng-options="ass.name for ass in dd1.Attributes"> 
  </select><br><br>

  <input ng-if="dd2" type="text" ng-model="dd2.name"><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```